How does Forced Parameterization impact queries when using SET options such as quoted identifier?
When using Simple Parameterization in the AdventureWorks database, you can execute the following query:
USE [AdventureWorks2022]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SELECT "True" FROM Person.Person WHERE FirstName = "John"

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

However, when you enable Forced Parameterization, this same query fails with:

Invalid column name 'True'.

If you remove the the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON at the end it succeeds, or if you add a GO after the SELECT, it also succeeds.
Is this something to do with how Forced Parameterization works? Just looking for an explanation so I can better understand it.

No it's probably to do with the way QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is parsed, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290663/multiple-set-quoted-identifier-within-one-script-takes-the-last-one/290681#290681 you need to check what the setting is before you run the batch.

@Charlieface How come this only impacts the value in the SELECT and not the WHERE clause though? If I have Forced Parameterization on and change the query to:
`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SELECT '"True"' FROM Person.Person WHERE FirstName = "John"
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`
Then this succeeds.

Possibly because of the way it caches the plan? I'll be honest: these are two features not likely to be used together. SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF is deprecated anyway, and Forced Parameterization is something that ideally shouldn't have been needed if the app was coded correctly..

@Charlieface Unfortunately it's all vendor code that is unparameterized. It would involve invididually modifying thousands of queries one by one in their slow app. Looking to hold out until they can migrate to a new app.
Every query ends with SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON even though there is no code afterwards, they believed that QUOTED_IDENTIFIER was an instance-level setting that needed to be reset every execution..
I was hoping to better understand why this is the behavior, your explanation would make sense if not for the quotes being fine in the WHERE clause.

Can you please post the full error message including the state number?  not just the error text

@ConorCunninghamMSFT
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Invalid column name 'True'.

The WHERE is the part that gets replaced by a parameter, so then there's no quotes left and the query succeeds

@siggemannen I guess the question is why the other strng literal is not replaced as well, under FP. This is probably better answered on [dba.se] and should be migrated there.

Are selected values ever parametrized? Don't think i've seen it at least, probably sql server is feeling lazy

The error is simple - with quoted identifier on,  "True" is not a column in table Person and binding fails.  When QI is off, it is just a literal you are projecting into the query.

@siggemannen If the WHERE is getting replaced by a parameter with FP, this would explain the error only appearing on "True" in the SELECT, except for the fact that this does not hold up as with Simple Parameterization the query succeeds.

From Charlies' post, the behavior of QI is dependent on the parsing, but @ConorCunninghamMSFT your comment doesn't answer the question of how/why forced parameterization impacts the logic of the query when using QI, as this error does not happen when using simple parameterization.

Well, does the where gets replaced in Simple Parameterization? I'm guessing in simple param there's nothing special happening with the query so it works as natural. But anyway, it's a lot of guesses, tsql has always had a lot of these quirks so i'm not surprised not everything works. Why do you even want forced parametrization? IMHO, it sucks

@siggemannen The WHERE would not get replaced in Simple. With Forced, the WHERE being replaced would explain why the Quoted Identifier error only shows up on the SELECT "True", but it doesn't answer why the ending SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON breaks that SELECT "True" only when using Forced Parameterization.
It is a less of needing to use it and more something interesting I ran into that I wasn't sure if it was a lack of understanding of the inner workings of FP on my part, a bug in SQL or something to do with QI.
